# How do you monkey-patch a Definitively-Typed definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using an npm module with a few missing definitions in the @types/*/index.d.ts file. 
I've submitted an issue on them.

In the meantime, I'd like to do something local to fix this, which turns out to be hard.

I tried just patching the index.d.ts file, but I'm using yarn, and it sniffs out the change and "fixes" the file every time I add another module.  So some kind of local patch would be best.

I've tried adding a local definition, but either I'm not doing it right or it's not possible.  Here's one attempt of many: a local definition, like

```
import {MapControl} from 'react-leaflet'
...
declare class MapControl extends React.Component<MapControlProps, any> {
    leafletElement: L.Control
}
```

doesn't help; the `import` doesn't consult the *implementation* of MapControl, just still sees that there isn't a *definition*.  Pointing it directly at `node_modules/react-leaflet/...` just runs into other problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for the module augmentation needs to be:

```
import * as React from "React";

declare module 'react-leaflet' {
    type MapControlPosition = 'topleft' | 'topright' | 'bottomleft' | 'bottomright';

    interface MapControlProps {
        position: MapControlPosition
    }

    class MapControl extends React.Component<MapControlProps, any> {
        leafletElement: L.Control
    }
}
```

See here for more details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but I wanted to add my example as I had to do this just yesterday

I have an app using the DataTables plugin for JQuery and I extended it to do a few extra things and when I switched to TypeScript I realized the typings lacked my extensions

```ts
    declare namespace DataTables {
    // the name() method is patched in to DataTables 1.x from the unreleased 2.0
        interface ColumnMethods {
            name: Function
        }
    // custom extensions to DataTables library
        interface ColumnSettings {
            searchType: string
        }
        interface AjaxDataRequestSearch {
            dataType: string, operator: string, valueTo: string
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it, I more or less trial-and-errored it and inferred from the .d.ts file. And yes I was too lazy to go look up the signature for the name() method, I just wanted the red squiggle to go away. This app is a recent port to TypeScript and there is days and days of work to type everything which probably will never get done but it is better than nothing.